# Find value in another table - Power BI (DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm trying to add a column in Power BI to see if a value appears in another table, without taking the case.

For example from the

Booking Table:

| User | Domain |
| --- | --- |
| exx | domain1 |
| EPO | domain2 |
| POA | domain3 |
| ER | domain4 |

and
Log Table:

| LogName | Date |
| --- | --- |
| RT | 12:31 |
| EXX | 11:23 |
| POA | 9:11 |
| rtt | 10:11 |

I want to see if the User appears in LogName and I'd like to have the output column3:

| User | Domain | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| exx | domain1 | 1 |
| EPO | domain2 | 0 |
| POA | domain3 | 1 |
| ER | domain4 | 0 |

I tried

```
CALCULATE(COUNT('Booking Table'[User]), 
        FILTER('Log Table', LOWER('Log Table'[LogName]) = LOWER('Booking Table'[User]) 
        ||
        LOWER('Log Table'[LogName]) = LOWER('Booking Table'[User])
        )
    )
```

but apparently it doesn't work properly.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Measure = 
var tbl = SUMMARIZE('Booking Table','Booking Table'[User],'Booking Table'[Domain],'Log Table'[LogName]) 
var count_user = COUNTX(tbl,'Log Table'[LogName])

return
IF(ISEMPTY(VALUES('Log Table'[LogName])),0,count_user)
```

Considering the relationship between the two tables is on User & LogName